# Java Flight Recorder dump shows timeline starting from 1/1/1970

Tags: java, jfr, jcmd

When starting the JFR using `jcmd` command and creating a recording dump, the resulting .jfr file when opened in mission control shows the timeline starting from 1/1/1970.

The issue occurs only for the *first recording dump after starting the application*, any subsequent dumps have correct timestamp.

Couldn't look up anything on web, would appreciate any tips on how to resolve it.

[image]

commands used:
`jcmd myApp JFR.start defaultrecording=true`
`jcmd $app_pid JFR.dump recording=0 filename=$dump_file`

JVM version:
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.271-b25) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_271-b25)`

**Edit**: this occurs only when using parameter `defaultrecording=true`

Comment: Hint : Unix time stamp start at the same time 01/01/1970

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug.

Most likely, the start time or the commit time of the event is 0. Need to know which event (type) that starts at 01/01/1970 and then it would probably not be that hard to fix.

Since you are running Oracle JDK 8, you might have a support contract and could request a fix.